# HttpServletRequestWrapper not working under Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, servlet-filters, servlet-3.0

My requirement is to decrypt the request body encrypted by my own algorithm
.

I've tried to extend `HttpServletRequestWrapper` and pass the new request to `doFilter`. But both `getInputStream` and `getReader` are not called, so not able to decrypt request body to plainText.

The order of the EncryptFilter is set first in `web.xml`.

**The URL I use is POST /user/add**

Here is my code

Subclass of HttpServletRequestWrapper:

```
class ResettableStreamHttpServletRequest extends
        HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private byte[] rawData;
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    private ResettableServletInputStream servletStream;

    public ResettableStreamHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
        this.request = request;
        this.servletStream = new ResettableServletInputStream();
    }


    public void resetInputStream(byte[] data) {
        servletStream.stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    }

    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        if (rawData == null) {
            rawData = IOUtils.toByteArray(this.request.getReader());
            servletStream.stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(rawData);
        }
        return servletStream;
    }

    @Override
    public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
        if (rawData == null) {
            rawData = IOUtils.toByteArray(this.request.getReader());
            servletStream.stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(rawData);
        }
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(servletStream));
    }


    private class ResettableServletInputStream extends ServletInputStream {

        private InputStream stream;

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            return stream.read();
        }
    }
}
```

`doFilter` related code:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        ServletRequest newRequest = new ResettableStreamHttpServletRequest((HttpServletRequest) request);
        ServletResponse newResponse = new EncryptedResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response);

        String body = IOUtils.toString(newRequest.getInputStream());
        String plainText = crypt.decrypt(body);
        LOGGER.debug(plainText);
        ((ResettableStreamHttpServletRequest) newRequest).resetInputStream(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        chain.doFilter(newRequest, newResponse);

        if (((EncryptedResponseWrapper) newResponse).getStatus() != HttpStatus.OK.value()) {
            response.getWriter().write(newResponse.toString());
            return;
        }

        String text = newResponse.toString();
        if (text != null) {
            String respPlainText = newResponse.toString();
            LOGGER.debug(respPlainText);
            String encrypted = crypt.encrypt(respPlainText);
            response.getWriter().write(encrypted);
        }
    }
```

And `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <absolute-ordering>
        <name>EncryptFilter</name>
        <name>encodingFilter</name>
    </absolute-ordering>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>EncryptFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.yuexunit.micro.filter.EncryptFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>EncryptFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: @TomSebastian neither getInputStream or getReader is called, no break point hit. And data is still encrypted, Spring controller reports required parameter is missing.

Comment: And you are calling a `/user` url? As that is what your filter is mapped to.

Comment: What url you are trying.I tried this locally , not having this issue

Comment: I use POST /user/add

Answer (score 0):

I used this approach to dump requests to solve a bug, but I got into an error due to the fact that when you use getReader() to save the request as a byte array, you are using the default machine encoding, and therefore you're not honouring the request's charset.

In my case, the client executed a POST whose payload is encoded with UTF-8, but my back-end happened to be on a Windows machine, whose encoding is, say, CP-1252. Your filter effectively takes the UTF-8 request, converts it into CP-1252 and all subsequent filters will see that. In my case, I have a REST controller expecting to receive that string (JSON), and I got a "400 Bad Request" error because of this.

The fixed solution goes around these lines (haven't tried this!):

```
class ResettableStreamHttpServletRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    private byte[] rawData;
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    private ResettableServletInputStream servletStream;

    ResettableStreamHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
        this.request = request;
        this.servletStream = new ResettableServletInputStream();
    }

    void resetInputStream() {
        servletStream.stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(rawData);
    }

    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        if (rawData == null) {
            rawData = IOUtils.toByteArray(this.request.getInputStream());
            servletStream.stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(rawData);
        }
        return servletStream;
    }

    @Override
    public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
        if (rawData == null) {
            rawData = IOUtils.toByteArray(this.request.getInputStream());
            servletStream.stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(rawData);
        }
        String encoding = getCharacterEncoding();
        if (encoding != null) {
            return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(servletStream, encoding));
        } else {
            return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(servletStream));
        }
    }

    private class ResettableServletInputStream extends ServletInputStream {
        private InputStream stream;

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            return stream.read();
        }
    }
}
```